# Defaultdict with Dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
a = [{'CohortList': [{'DriverValue': 0.08559936}, {'DriverValue': 0.08184596527051588}], 
      '_id': {'DriverName': 'Yield', 'MonthsOnBooks': 50, 'SegmentName': 'LTV110-Super Prime'}},
     {'CohortList': [{'DriverValue': 2406.04329}, {'DriverValue': 2336.0058100690103}, ], 
      '_id': {'DriverName': 'ADB', 'MonthsOnBooks': 15, 'SegmentName': 'LTV110-Super Prime'}},
     {'CohortList': [{'DriverValue': 2406.04329}, {'DriverValue': 2336.0058100690103}, ], 
      '_id': {'DriverName': 'ADB', 'MonthsOnBooks': 16, 'SegmentName': 'LTV110-Prime'}}]
```

I want to construct a list of dictionary with values as lists from the above dict set like this

```
    {
    "LTV110-Prime": [
        {
            "ADB": [
                {
                    "16": 1500
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Yield": []
        }
    ],
    "LTV110-Super Prime": [
        {
            "ADB": [
                {
                    "15": 1500
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Yield": [
                {
                    "50": 0.09
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Essentially, I want to group ADB and Yield for each segments with their values.

This is what I have done so far to achieve this target. The values for ADB are mean of DriverValue from CohortList list. I have used statistics.mean to find out the mean of the mapped values.

```
sg_wrap = defaultdict(dict)
for p in pp_data:
    mapped = map(lambda d: d.get('DriverValue', 0), p['CohortList'])
    dic = {p['_id']['MonthsOnBooks']: statistics.mean(mapped)}

    print(p)
print(sg_wrap)
```

I am not able to append the Drivers to the inner dict. Please help.

Comment: In other words, you have a set of objects (no need for dicts in input), that you want to group by segment name, and output statistics for driver name (not clear what happens if there are multiple records)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are wrapping everything into lists, you do not need a `defaultdict(dcit)` but a `defaultdict(list)`.

The following seems to work:

```
result = defaultdict(list)
for entry in a:
    id_ = entry["_id"]
    name, months, segment = id_["DriverName"], id_["MonthsOnBooks"], id_["SegmentName"]
    values = [x["DriverValue"] for x in entry["CohortList"]]
    d = {name: [{months: statistics.mean(values)}]}
    result[segment].append(d)
```

Result is

```
{'LTV110-Prime': [{'ADB': [{16: 2371.0245500345054}]}],
 'LTV110-Super Prime': [{'Yield': [{50: 0.08372266263525793}]},
                        {'ADB': [{15: 2371.0245500345054}]}]}
```